# If both trend and seasonality exist, which should we remove first

Tags: python-3.x, time-series, trend

I have in my time series data both trend and seasonal components. I have been searching for methods to remove both trend and seasonality. However if both components exist:

1. Should we detrend --> deseasonalize on the detrended values ?
2. Should we deseasonalize --> detrend on deseasonalized values ?

I have my data in a weekly basis, I have a linear trend and seasonal components that repeat every 2 weeks.

You can see in the following picture I have a decomposition of my time series into trend, seasonality, and residuals. I want to be able to extract trend and seasonality in order to get a residual as shown in the figure.

However I have been searching over the internet and all methods so far rotate around applying differencing to either detrend or deseasonalize, but I want to actually do both to obtain a residual void of any trend or seasonal components.

So what are the steps that I must do to extract trend and seasonality (which one should I do first)?

[Time Series Decomposition Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S3SSR.jpg)

I will really appreciate the feedback!

Comment: I'm not sure if anyone can answer this question when we don't know the type of data, trend or season.

Comment: That's still not very informative. Can you show some example data? What do you want the data to look like? What did you try so far? We have no clue what you're doing without seeing it ourselves.

Comment: @NoSplitSherlock sorry for the inconvenience, I hope the question is clearer now ?

Comment: No problem. :) So to make something clear, do you want to *remove* seasonality and trend from a set of data or do you want to *extract* it? Those are very different.

Comment: @NoSplitSherlock Thank you for your feedback, I want to do both. I want to extract trend and seasonality to put them in seperate columns in my dataframe, and I want to remove them in order to get a residual void of both (example: by differencing)

Comment: Can you show some code? I don't understand how you plot seasonality if you don't have it in a frame already.